# Disable any sort of redirection from the server

Tags: javascript, html

On a website i have i am using a free hosting service for one my forms, after the form is submitted, it redirects me somewhere else. If i put the whole form in a div, is there some way to give certain properties to this div to prevent any sort of client/server side redirection specifically from that div?

```
<div id="DisableRedirect">HERE GOES THE FORM</div>
```

Comment: When you submit a form it'll always redirect somewhere. Are you self posting this form and its taking you somewhere else totally?

Comment: Yes. I guess youre right it has to redirect since it needs to submit the data. I guess the only way to overcome the solution is to pay for premium service to disable the redirection. That sucks. I'll find another way. Thanks.

Comment: you want to send data without redirecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment above you can't create a form which can't be redirected. When a form is posted it'll always redirect to self or another page.